# HTML/TS - Obtaining value totals from column values

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an ngFor populating table values. One column provides quantities and I’m looking to total the values of this column only. I can only find ways that give the ‘rows’ total but I need the value to have the quantity total. I've tried using the code below, the result is NaN, I'm wondering is there a more simplistic way to calculate from an ngFor column?

-- HTML --

```
<tr class="table" *ngFor="let row of rows">
   <td>{{row.quantity}}</td>
 <td>
   {{row.custName}}
   <p class="instructions">{{row.startDate}}</p>
 </td>
</tr>

<div class="row">
    <h5 style="font-weight: bold">
      Total: {{totalQty}}
    </h5>
</div>
```

-- TS --

```
totalMeds: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.quantityTotal();
  }

  quantityTotal() {
    this.total1 = this.column1.filter(item => 
    item.administration.quantity.valueOf());
    this.total2 = this.column2.filter(item => 
    item.administration.quantity.valueOf());
    this.total3 = this.column3.filter(item => item.administration.quantity.valueOf());

    this.totalQty = this.total1 * this.total2 * this.total3;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) -or iterate over the array-

```
quantityTotal(){
   return this.rows.reduce((a:number,b:any)=>b.administration.quantity?
                    a+b.administration.quantity:
                    a
   ,0)
}
```

See that reduce is only a compact way to say

```
a=0
this.rows.forEach(x=>{
   a=b.administration.quantity?
        a+b.administration.quantity:a
})
return a
```